# Image goes out of flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an image that I want to fit in flexbox.
Card has fixed size, and I want the image to fit in without specifying size but it just ignores flexbox.

```css
.card {
    border: 2px solid #072227;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 40vw;
}
.card__profile-image {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.img__cont img {
    height: 100%;
}
.img__cont {

}
.card__name {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card__section card__profile-image">
        <div class="img__cont">
            <!-- <div class="image"> -->
                <img src="https://scontent.fkiv9-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/317808332_704091791080096_1098720845539800517_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=FFO8v3dmkM8AX_aR9js&_nc_ht=scontent.fkiv9-2.fna&oh=00_AfDQCQcHmZH4QuauHvdxiLEFX0rExv9gMENs8ptsEzdoYg&oe=63DEF9AD" alt="Profile Picture" />
            <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="card__name">Alex Hill</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card__section">
        <div class="card__info-top">
            <span class="info__top-job">Senior Developer | A1-D</span>
            <span class="info__top-contact">alexhill#0001</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card__info-bottom">6 000$</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/watermelon-and-me/pen/jOpQGje

UPD.
Expected result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/smvy0.png

Answer (score 0):

On `.img__cont` and `.img__cont img`, set `max-width` and `max-height` to 100% each.

```css
.card {
    border: 2px solid #072227;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 40vw;
}
.card__profile-image {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.img__cont, .img__cont img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.card__name {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card__section card__profile-image">
        <div class="img__cont">
            <!-- <div class="image"> -->
                <img src="https://scontent.fkiv9-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/317808332_704091791080096_1098720845539800517_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=FFO8v3dmkM8AX_aR9js&_nc_ht=scontent.fkiv9-2.fna&oh=00_AfDQCQcHmZH4QuauHvdxiLEFX0rExv9gMENs8ptsEzdoYg&oe=63DEF9AD" alt="Profile Picture" />
            <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="card__name">Alex Hill</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card__section">
        <div class="card__info-top">
            <span class="info__top-job">Senior Developer | A1-D</span>
            <span class="info__top-contact">alexhill#0001</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card__info-bottom">6 000$</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, it partly works, but the image takes 100% of the card, and doesn't give any space for the name.
Here's more detailed example of what I want to achieve: https://imgur.com/a/wWiCsBr